# How to ensure Buttons from material ui all have the same length and height

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
<Button>very long long long long long long label</Button>
<Button>Short label</Button>
```

The 2 buttons above will be of different length due to the different label of the label. How can I ensure that they will remain the same length?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `minWidth` and `maxWidth` properties.
For instance:
<Button style={{maxWidth: '10px', maxHeight: '10px', minWidth: '10px', minHeight: '10px'}}/>

Answer (score 0):

**You can fixed it into theme.**

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const defaultTheme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton:{
     root: {
     // Some CSS
      minWidth : '10px',
      maxWidth : '100px',

     },    
    },

  },

});

export default defaultTheme;
```